# What could go wrong in switching HTML encoding from UTF-8 to UTF-16?

Tags: html, encoding, utf-8, utf-16

What are the implications of a change from UTF-8 to UTF-16 for HTML encoding?  I would like to know your thoughts on the issue.  Are there things I need to think of before making such a change?

Note: Interested due to enormous amounts of japanese and chinese text I need to handle.

Comment: Why do you want to change? UTF-16 would need 16 bit for each character while UTF-8 would only need 16 bit from U+0080 on. So every ASCII characters will be encoded like ASCII.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I can think of a few things that will go wrong:

1. You MUST specify that it's UTF-16 in the HTTP header.  Unlike UTF-8, UTF-16 is **not** ASCII compatible, which means that everything needs to be in UTF-16 from the start.
2. Older clients don't support UTF-16.  For example, anything on Windows 9x.  Possibly Mac OS9 as well.
3. Oh, wait, I almost forgot: North America and European copies of Windows XP don't have Asian fonts installed by default.

Comment: re 3: That issue is independant of whether the characters are encoded in UTF-8 or UTF-16.

Comment: True, but I thought I'd throw it in as long as I was listing problems.

Comment: Of course, some of these are less relevant now in 2017 than they were when I originally wrote this in 2009.

Answer (score 8):

- Your bandwidth consumption is likely to nearly double, assuming most of your HTML is ASCII
- Clients which incorrectly assume UTF-8 (or ASCII) will be confused

Why do you *want* to change to UTF-16?

Comment: Or bandwith consumption might nearly halve.

Comment: Yes, if most of your HTML is non-ASCII. Of course, given that the HTML tag and attribute names themselves are ASCII, it would have to contain a good "content to markup" ratio.

Comment: The OP mentions large amounts of chinese and japanese text, but good point about the markup.

Comment: Ah - the Chinese and Japanese text bit was added after I'd answered :)

Answer (score 4):

There is also the byte order which becomes an issue with anything above 8-bit data. UTF encoded files begin with a byte order mark which is used to determine the byte order, or endianness, of that file.

[Wikipedia has a quite good explanation of this.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte-order_mark)

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know all modern browsers support UTF-16 encoding. But as others have pointed out, you should declare the encoding explicitly. Not all browsers and platforms will support all unicode characters, but I think this is regardless of which encoding you use.

However, if bandwith is a big issue you should probably consider gzipping the HTML. This will save much more bandwidth than switching encoding.

Answer (score 3):

Very nice article you have held here. Fundamentals states, "When a unique character encoding is required, the character encoding MUST be UTF-8, UTF-16 or UTF-32. US-ASCII is upwards-compatible with UTF-8 (an US-ASCII string is also a UTF-8 string, see [RFC 3629]), and UTF-8 is therefore appropriate if compatibility with US-ASCII is desired." In practice, compatibility with US-ASCII is so useful it's almost a requirement. The W3C wisely explains, "In other situations, such as for APIs, UTF-16 or UTF-32 may be more appropriate. Possible reasons for choosing one of these include efficiency of internal processing and interoperability with other processes."

Answer (score -6):

I suspect most browsers won't even show your pages.