# Should I change from UTF-8 to UTF-16 to accommodate Chinese characters in my HTML?

Tags: html, utf-8, utf-16

I am using ASP.NET MVC, MS SQL and IIS.  I have a few users that have used Chinese characters in their profile info.  However, when I display this information is shows up as `&#230;Ž&#229;&#188;&#183;&#232;&#175;` but they are correct in my database.  Currently my UTF for my HTML pages is set to UTF-8.  Should I change it to UTF-16?  I understand there are a [few problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/865168/what-could-go-wrong-in-switching-html-encoding-from-utf-8-to-utf-16) that can come from this but what are my choices?

Comment: are you using `htmlentities()` or `htmlspecialchars()` when outputting?

Comment: those are only for PHP, right?

Comment: Have you tried specifying your character set in your meta tags? https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations

Answer (score 27):

UTF-8 and UTF-16 encode exactly the same set of characters.  It's not that UTF-8 doesn't cover Chinese characters and UTF-16 does.
UTF-16 uses uniformly 16 bits to represent a character; while UTF-8 uses 1, 2, 3, up to a max of 4 bytes, depending on the character, so that an ASCII character is represented still as 1 byte.
Start with [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) to get the idea behind it.

So, there's little chance switching to UTF-16 will help you at all. There's a chance it makes things worse, as is discussed in the SO question you linked above. There's a problem somewhere else in your setup, which does not correctly take into account non-ASCII or non-Latin-1 characters. Make sure every part of your setup works in UTF-8.

Comment: UTF-16 can have 2 code units 16 bits each, taking 32 bits in total to represent a character, see some examples in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16

Comment: @yuji Actually UTF-8 can use up to 4 bytes. Initially it was 6 but after realising that this would be an overkill (we only use around 110.000 today while 6 bytes would allow for 2 billion!) people settled for 4 bytes http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3629

Answer (score 6):

Any UTF coding should work the same in their ability to represent Unicode characters so switching to UTF-16 wouldn't help. There's an encoding issue somewhere and with UTF-16 you would only end up with different wrong HTML representation. Of course if you have some library that simply encodes non-ASCII characters as entities and does support wide characters, your problem may be solved by the switch. There are however characters that need even 2 wide characters and these would still be shown wrong, although users might rarely notice. The best option would be to have whatever is producing the HTML to interpret your UTF-8 correctly.