# Will storing kanji charecters in UTF-8 lead to data corruption or loss

Tags: oracle, utf-8, hive

I want to understand whether the chinese or japanese charecters entered by the users will be corrupted or lost if My database has utf-8 as the default character set.

Comment: It seems that according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3864842/should-i-change-from-utf-8-to-utf-16-to-accommodate-chinese-characters-in-my-htm UTF-8 should suffice.

Comment: and what about the client side? ("entered by the users" is a bit unclear)

Comment: No, UTF-8 supports any possible unicode character. But you have to ensure that also your client application is set probably for UTF-8 Sometimes it is not so obvious where to set it.