# How to implement a Dart + PostgreSQL Stack

Tags: postgresql, dart

I'm looking for examples of a basic CRUD application in Dart utilizing a postgres database.

I found a stack question from user cc young that described a dart web server with dart clients and I was wondering how to implement such a solution.

"... running dart web server, with dart on clients as well. web data is saved in files and in a postgres database." ([Should a Dart web server use UTF-16 encoding for everything?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20112040/for-dart-web-server-make-sense-to-push-everything-to-utf-16-encoding))

Answer (score 1):

There is a [pub package](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/postgresql) available for working with PostgreSQL databases. The readme provides some usage examples.

Comment: I believe they are all examples for server-side connections; I think I'm missing the client side integration via dart.

Comment: You could create a RESTful api interface that your browser client can use. The package route can help you with this task: http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/route

Comment: For the client site send JSON messages to the server. There's an example here https://www.dartlang.org/articles/json-web-service/

Comment: dart 2 incompatible